# How to strip and use title() in list and dictionary

Tags: python

I know this is a newbie question. But I'm still having trouble using `.strip()` and `.title()` with a list or a dictionary. I'd like to normalize both but can't find how.

```
favorite_languages = {
        'JENNA': 'python',
        'louis': 'C',
        'liOnEl': 'Ruby',
        'maude': 'Javascript',
        }

friends = ['  JeNNa', 'LIONEL  ']


for name in favorite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title().strip())

    if name.title().strip() in friends:
        print("Hi " + name + ", I can see your favorite language is " +
            favorite_languages[name] + "!")
```

Comment: What's the problem? What would be the *expected result*?

Comment: The code doesn't work. I'd like that when a normalized key in dictionary is the same as a normalized name in friends, some message appear. I don't know how to do it. I can print it with title() and strip() but how can I do it on the data itself so that the loop don't see '    JeNNa' but 'Jenna' and compare it not to 'JENNA' but to 'Jenna'.

Expected result would be: "Hi Jenna, I can see your favorite language is python".

Answer (score 1):

First, normalise your `favorite_languages`:

```
In [605]: fav_lang_norm = { x.strip().title() : favorite_languages[x] for x in favorite_languages }; fav_lang_norm
Out[605]: {'Jenna': 'python', 'Lionel': 'Ruby', 'Louis': 'C', 'Maude': 'Javascript'}
```

Then, normalise your `friends` list:

```
In [606]: friends_norm = [x.strip().title() for x in friends]; friends_norm
Out[606]: ['Jenna', 'Lionel']
```

Iterate over the normalised dictionary:

```
for name, language in fav_lang_norm.items():
    if name in friends_norm:
        print("Hi " + name + ", I can see your favorite language is " +
            language + "!")
```

You'd better hope your friends list is case insensitive...

---

Second approach, consider you have a huge `favorite_languages` dictionary with a million records:

```
favorite_languages = {...} # 1 million
```

Step 1: Normalise your `favourite_languages` dict *only*:

```
fav_lang_norm = { x.strip().title() : favorite_languages[x] for x in favorite_languages }
```

Step 2: Iterate over your `friends` list:

```
for name in friends: # friends is not normalised
    name_norm = name.strip().title()
    if name_norm in fav_lang_norm:
        print("Hi " + name_norm + ", I can see your favorite language is " +
            fav_lang_norm[name_norm] + "!")
```

Comment: I guess using `.items()` in the dict comprehension and the loops would make it a bit clearer, otherwise +1

Comment: And lets hope the OP  never gets any friends with names that only differ in casing ;-)

Comment: @Anthon Haha yes indeed. That is one caveat I should mention.

Comment: Thanks... But this is so much complex for me. I sure understand this must be the most efficient way to do it. But would it be possible to work it from my own code? What are the 605 and 606 exactly? (Yes, I know, I am a newbie)... I get an error here: In [605]: fav_lang_norm = { x.strip().title() : favorite_languages[x] for x in favorite_languages }; fav_lang_norm
Out[605]: {'Jenna': 'python', 'Lionel': 'Ruby', 'Louis': 'C', 'Maude': 'Javascript'}

Comment: @JohnStraight Ignore In and Out. They are my IPython terminal prompts. Also, copy In[605], In[606] (without the prompts), and paste it above your for loop, then replace your for loop with my for loop.

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks... I understand now. It seems to work!

Comment: @JohnStraight Do consider accepting this answer -- it helps the community by and large :)

Comment: But what if I'd like to normalize automatically what are in the dict and list without typing the actuall results themselves? (imagine 1 million results)

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: @JohnStraight 1) That's a bit complicated. First up I would recommend you keep a normalised copy of the dictionary. Second, the list does not need pre-normalisation. You may iterate over the list instead of the dictionary, and inside each iteration normalise the element and then do the lookup. 2) There is a tick mark next to my answer. Click on it and it should turn green.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think my mistake was I didn't know how to introduce the .title().strip() in the iteration and tried to = to an existing variable (name). Creating a new one made it work.

A last question: how would it be possible to normalize differently the "key" vs. the "value" in the dict? Let's say I want the key with title() and the value with upper(), how would you do that?

You completely answered my question. Thanks a lot. I am new here: do I need to click somewhere to show that my question have been answered? Thanks again.

Comment: I was also wondering if it would be possible to explain this: 

fav_lang_norm = { users.strip().title() : favorite_languages[users] for users in favorite_languages }

I don't understand how it works. It works, but what is accomplished exactly?

Again, sorry for the newbie question. I am really new to python and new as well to programming. Just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: @JohnStraight Questions about the code I can deal with. Other questions become a pain to answer and turns comments into their own Q and A board. To preserve sanity you should just look it up or ask a question. As to the code I've used it's called a dictionary comprehension. As you iterate over some iterable you specify key-value pairs to fill the dict.